# convert original URL to friendly URL via mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have 2 type of url in my page.

1- http://www.example.com/index.php?id=12

I want always this:

http://www.example.com/12

But for anything else like:

2- http://www.example.com/index.php?id=12&id2=123&asd=qwe&svd=sdf...

I want it with no change:

http://www.example.com/?id=12&id2=123&asd=qwe&svd=sdf...

SO I want only redirect for `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=12`

I try this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]
```

it works only for first (http://www.example.com/index.php?id=12)

but for second,it redirect to (http://www.example.com/***)

I read in stackoveflow I must use `[QSA,L]`

So I try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [QSA,L]
```

But I got 500 error (Internal Server Error)

this is my complete code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]
```

---EDIT ---

I could do it with this

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/([^/]+)/?([^/]*) /index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

for example www.example.com/123  works!

but  www.example.com/index.php?id=123 not redirect to www.example.com/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `http://example.com/index.php?id=foo` to `http://example.com/foo` you can use the following rules in `root/.htaccesso` :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)Redirect "/index.php?id=foo" to "/foo"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
#2)The rule bellow will internally map "/foo" to "/index.php?id=foo"#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

[Tested] This works on my apache server.

Comment: thanks. but 'id2=123&asd=qwe&svd=sdf' is an example. every name and value can come here...also for id=12 , 12 is not fixed. it can be every number or char.

Comment: **Or** you can fix your last rule to match  the specific url


    `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [QSA,L]`

Comment: thanks but I want redirect only www.example.com/?id=123 format,not for  other...also QSA return me an internal server error

Comment: QSA does not return Server error, you need to use the R flag instead of QSA because you want to redirect from query strings to a clean url